# Copying last n lines to a new file and then removing the n lines from original

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

So I have a file where I want to move the last 3000 lines to another different file, and then create a new file from the original without the last 3000 lines.

I'm using a Mac and the command I used is as follows:

```
tail -n 3000 fer2017-testing-reduced.arff >> fer2017-training-reduced-3000-more-instances.arff; head -n -3000 fer2017-testing-reduced.arff > fer2017-testing-reduced-3000-less-instances.arff
```

However when I run this, I get the error:

```
head: illegal line count -- -3000
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, or if this may be a mac issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all versions of `head` support negative line counts.
The default installed on macOS doesn't.

If you have [`coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) installed (If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed you can do this: `brew install coreutils`) you should be able to use `ghead -n -3000`.

Answer (score 3):

If other tools are allowed, perhaps go for `sed`

```
sed -n '3000,${p}' file > filenew # print lines 3000 to end to new file
sed -i '3000,${d}' file # Use inplace edit to delete lines 3000 to end from orig.
```

The advantage here is that the `$` auto matches the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Read more info from why [POSIX `head` and `tail` not feature equivalent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/posix-head-and-tail-not-feature-equivalent), the POSIX version of `head` does *not* accept negative integers for the `-n` option.

Qutoting from the [POSIX `head`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/head/) command documentation,

> `-n number` The first number lines of each input file shall be copied  to  standard  output.
>            The application shall ensure that the number option-argument is a positive decimal integer.

You are better changing `head -n -3000` to `tail -n +3001` to start from line `3000` to end of the file. Or use GNU supported `head` command which on Mac is available as part of GNU coreutils.